# Bacula: When a backup job fails, is it possible to run a different backup job?

Tags: backup, bacula

When a Bacula backup job fails, is it possible to run a different backup job ?

I mean something like *"after failure of Job A, run Job B"*.

Is there a specific directive in the Job Resource?

EDIT1: I tryed the directive `Run After Failed Job = command` which can be used for running a script like `echo "run job=my_job yes" | bconsole` but seems that the script doesn't nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved my goal with this *Job Resource* directive:

```
Job {
...
    RunScript {
        Command = "/etc/bacula/scripts/run_my_job"
        RunsWhen = After
        RunsOnFailure = yes
        RunsOnClient  = no
        RunsOnSuccess = no
    }
...
}
```

`/etc/bacula/scripts/run_my_job` needs to be `chmod +x`

`/etc/bacula/scripts/run_my_job` content is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "run job=my_job yes" | bconsole
```

Comment: Does the `console` instead of `command` works too?

Comment: In the `Job` definition?

Answer (score 1):

In the Job definition,

replace

```
    Command = "/etc/bacula/scripts/run_my_job"
```

by

```
    Console = "run job=my_job yes"
```

No log is visible in the output of the job, because it is placed on job N°0 (not checked), but the command will be executed.

```
Job {
...
    RunScript {
        Console = "run job=my_job yes"
        RunsWhen = After
        RunsOnFailure = yes
        RunsOnClient  = no
        RunsOnSuccess = no
    }
...
}
```